# How to setup multiple webhooks in Watson Assistant

Tags: node.js, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions, watson-assistant-solutions

I tried I have multiple actions in IBM cloud functions. I need Watson Assistant to call different ones when certain nodes hit.

My question is, there's only the possibility to put one webhook in Watson assistant's options. I understand that I'd have to code an action that detects the params sent and invokes the proper action. I tried using the Axios NPM as you can see below but it always fails when Watson Assistant try's to run it. It's giving me authorization errors. My current IBM Cloud Function namespace is CF-Based.

Here's the code im trying to get using to call my "emails" action:

```
const axios = require("axios");
// Change to your "BASE_URL". Type in the "Web Action" url without the name of it at the end. (must NOT contains the end '/')
// All "Actions" must be within the same namespace.
const BASE_URL = "https://us-south.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/namespaces"
const POST = "post";
const GET = "get";
const ANY = "any";
const ALL = "all";

/* List all your API methods
    1. method - API Name (This is the "Actions" name at the end of the Web Action URL or just the name)
    2. attr - Attributes that should be available in the params object
    3. rule - Currently supports 2 rules;
                a) any - params is valid if "any" of the attributes are present
                b) all - params is valid only if all attributes are present
    4. httpmethod -Supports "POST" and "GET"
    5. contains - Use for validating GET URL parameters
*/
const API_METHODS = [{
        method: "Emails", // Change to your API method "Please put the function name located at the end of the url without "/" example "Email"
        attr: ["client_email", "department_email"],
        rule: ANY,
        httpmethod: POST,
        contains: null
    },
    {
        method: "testapi", // If Watson needs to "GET" information to a user or athenticate a user
        attr: [],
        rule: ALL,
        httpmethod: GET,
        contains: "?ID="
    },
]

// Returns true if the "params" is valid for the given API method
function isValidParam(method, params = {}) {
    var attributes = [];
    attributes = method.attr;
    var isAny = method.rule === ANY;
    for (let index = 0; index < attributes.length; index++) {
        const attr = attributes[index];
        if (isAny) {
            if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(params, attr)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(params, attr)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (attributes.length === 0 && method.contains) {
        return (JSON.stringify(params).indexOf(method.contains) > -1)
    }

    // if the code reaches this position, inverse of "isAny" should return the actual validation status.
    return !isAny;
}

async function main(params) {
    var result = [];

    // Stop on first failure
    // We iterate through all API methods. Because there can be more than one matching API for the given param type
    for (let index = 0; index < API_METHODS.length; index++) {
        const apiMethod = API_METHODS[index];
        const url = BASE_URL + '/' + apiMethod.method;

        if (isValidParam(apiMethod, params)) {
            let response = apiMethod.httpmethod === POST ?
                await axios.post(url, params) :
                await axios.get(url + params); // Expects the parameter to be a string in this case like '?id=345343'

            console.log(response);

            result.push({
                sent: true,
                url: url,
                request: params,
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        sent: true,
        details: result
    };
}
// THe part of the code that needs to be copied to call other functions within the namespace.


/* const API_METHODS = [{
 method: "Emails", // Change to your API method "Please put the function name located at the end of the url without "/" example "Email"
 *   attr: ["bamboo_email", "latitude_email", "latest_r_email", "department_email"],
    rule: ANY,
    httpmethod: POST,
    contains: null
},
{
    method: "testapi", // If Watson needs to "GET" information to a user or athenticate a user
    attr: [],
    rule: ALL,
    httpmethod: GET,
    contains: "?ID="
},
]  */
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Actually there's no error. It runs without issue. The emails don't get sent though. When I try with the Emails action api link directly, it works, so it isn't a problem with the "Emails" action

Comment: You said "authorization error" and that something is not working. Show that code and the error or close the question.